# How to get the Binding element of a collection inside an item template in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a custom control RadCoverFlow that takes a collection of Image as an itemsSource.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Black">
    <telerik:RadCoverFlow x:Name="coverFlow"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ViewImages, Mode=OneWay}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
    </telerik:RadCoverFlow>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to define the widh, the height and a couple of other properties of the Images using a data template. My problem is that in the Data Template, I need to specify a source for each images, but that source is already specified in code.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
        <Image Source="" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" telerik:RadCoverFlow.EnableLoadNotification="True" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

How can I not re-specify the Source, or bind the source to the Source like {Binding ViewImages[i]}, what would be i in this case?

Thank You

Comment: Where is the source specified? is it on the ViewImage objects?

Comment: The DataContext is set in the code-behind to my ViewModel class, which has the ViewImages Collection and is responsible for setting the source of the Images and adding the Images to the ViewImages collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your business objects and your UI should be completely separate, so your `ItemsSource` should not have `Image` UI objects

But that said, try and use an implicit style to set your properties

```
<telerik:RadCoverFlow.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
        <Setter Property="telerik:RadCoverFlow.EnableLoadNotification" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</telerik:RadCoverFlow.Resources>
```

Comment: This worked, but I took your advice and changed my collection to hold BitmapImages instead. Then set my DataTemplate with Source="{Binding}". It works, but I was wondering what does Source="{Binding}" do exactly?

Comment: @didibus It binds the property to whatever the current `DataContext` is. In your case, the `DataContext` was your `BitmapImage`, so it is setting the source to the `BitmapImage` instead of a property on the `BitmapImage`

Comment: Oh, so if I understand correctly, inside the DataTemplate, the DataContext is set to each item in the collection?